# how to repeat the images in a tableview cell?.there are only 5 images i just want to repeat the images and it should contain 100 rows only

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

```
class InfotableViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
let myActivityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

var name = [String]()
var imagearray=[UIImage]()

@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 150
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! profileTableViewCell
   cell.tableimage.image = nil;
    cell.tableimage.image = imagearray[indexPath.row] as! UIImage
    cell.tablelabel.text = name[indexPath.row] as! String
    self.myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    return cell

}
```

Comment: Please improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 100
}
```

and this,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! profileTableViewCell
    cell.tableimage.image = nil;
    let index = indexPath.row%5
    cell.tableimage.image = imagearray[index] as! UIImage
    cell.tablelabel.text = name[indexPath.row] as! String
    self.myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    return cell

}
```

Comment: what is the count of name array?

Comment: Its getting fatal error in cell.tablelabel.text = name[indexPath.row] as! String in this line .The image is working fine.But i need to list the name also

Comment: @BhuvaneswariLakshminarayanan can you please tell me what is the count of name array?

Comment: count of name array is 5

Comment: then you should use same as imagearray, name[index] as! String, FYI, it will repeat name same as images, don't know why you want output like this :)

Comment: name = ["image1","image2","image3","image4","image5"]
        imagearray = [UIImage(named:"1")!,UIImage(named:"2")!,UIImage(named:"3")!,UIImage(named:"4")!,UIImage(named:"5")!]          
i m having like this for image its working fine .but for name array its saying fatal array

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1")

    cell?.textLabel?.text = (list1[indexPath.row % list1.count] 

    cell?.imageView?.image = (list1[indexPath.row  % list1.count] 

    return cell!

}
```

Comment: But i want to delete the particular row? can anyone help me?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.